# scons and "Test Anything Protocol" integration

Tags: unit-testing, scons

I'm looking to [scons](http://scons.org/)-ify a project that has a [*Test Anything Protocol*](http://testanything.org/) testing framework.

Can anyone give me direction on prior work here or smoothly integrating the two?  (Is there a native python TAP harness, should I shell out to a custom [`Test::Harness`](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Test-Harness/) wrapper, etc.?)  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've added support to format SCons own unittest results in TAP format. You probably need more generalized test harness support than unittests, but that should be a good [starting point](https://bitbucket.org/scons/scons/src/tip/testing/framework/TestUnit/taprunner.py?at=default).

It will be nice to get end-to-end SCons tests results also printed in TAP format, but I have no idea when it may happen.